# Does xdebug beautify var_dump?

Tags: xdebug, var-dump

According to this article, http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803, var_dump is supposed to beautify the outputs.

I have installed xdebug on my local host with PHP Version 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.2.
I have this in my php.ini outputs.

> This program makes use of the Zend
>   Scripting Language Engine: Zend Engine
>   v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend
>   Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

However when I use var_dump(), nothing changes.

Does xdebug really beautify the var_dump outputs?

If so, how can I fix it?

This is my details of xdebug in php.ini

```
xdebug
xdebug support  enabled
Version     2.1.0

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol     $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   netbeans-xdebug netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.manual_url   http://www.php.net  http://www.php.net
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A PHP patch about this was accepted yesterday: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/error-formatting-for-developers Regards.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to have [html errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors) turned on in your php config as well

Comment: I also had to restart the apache server.

Comment: I've been looking for this so long. This also works on cloud9, which has xdebug setup by default but it didn't look like it was doing anything, because this was turned Off -.-